# How to write multilingual applications in Clojure?

Tags: internationalization, clojure, multilingual, compojure

I'm trying to figure out how to create a Compojure-based web-site with multilingual support. Is there any solutions like i18n or something like that?

Answer (score 18):

The easiest way is to replace all your localized strings with a function calls like:

`(i18n lang "help")`

And implement that function to read localized string from a `.properties` file determined by `lang` parameter.

For that you don't need any libraries. It's a simple function.

To avoid reading files all the time you could read them in memory during your applications start with a `def` into a map named `loaded-property-files` where, `lang` is the key and the value is a map of message keys and appropriate localized messages.

This can be done like this:

```
(defn load-property-files [langs]
  (let [default (into {} (read-properties "locale.properties"))]
      (apply merge 
       (for [lang langs] 
        (assoc {} lang
         (merge default 
          (into {} (read-properties (str "locale_" lang ".properties")))))))))

(def loaded-property-files 
      (load-property-files ["en" "es" "de"]))
```

If file loading performance is not a problem, but you'd like to be able to change the files more easily during runtime, just change the `def` to a function.

The function `read-properties` (originally from old `clojure.contrib`) looks like this:

```
(defn read-properties
  "Read properties from file-able."
  ([fileable]
   (into {} (map #(vector (keyword (key %)) (val %))
    (try
      (with-open [f (java.io.FileInputStream. (new java.io.File fileable))]
        (doto (new java.util.Properties)
          (.load f)))
    (catch java.io.FileNotFoundException e {})))))
  ([fileable defaults] (merge (read-properties fileable) defaults)))
```

The localization string from `default` file would be used whenever that key isn't found in the specified map, i.e. new string that has just been added, and no one translated it in Spanish yet, would be shown in language from default `locale.properties`

Then your `i18n` function looks like this:

```
(defn i18n [lang code]
  ((loaded-property-files lang) code))
```

Comment: It might be reasonable to reuse the existing JVM resource bundle infrastructure inside this function.  It ain't pretty, but at least it defines mechanisms for well-known naming schemes and how to find bundles with a series of fallback choices so you can degrade gracefully and reduce overlap.

Comment: @Alex: I agree, but I'm not very familiar with direct use of built-in bundle support. Most of the time I either used a framework to do it or parsed the text file myself, like here.

Answer (score 7):

There is a new i18n library: https://github.com/ptaoussanis/tower with this rationale:

> Tower is an attempt to present a simple, idiomatic internationalization and localization story for Clojure. It wraps standard Java functionality where possible, but it isn't afraid to step away from Java conventions when there's a good reason to.

Answer (score 5):

I created [clji18n](https://github.com/paraseba/clji18n) for this, but I had to switch to other project before completing it. It's "almost" usable, you can give it a try.

Answer (score 4):

kotarak's j18n (note that there is another j18n library for Java but they are different ones) seems good.

https://bitbucket.org/kotarak/j18n